# What happen when i run array.some in array filter

Tags: javascript

I just learned a new trick to find the same object in 2 array object, it works very well. it uses array.filter and array.some, as code bellow, but I don't understand how `filter()` can run when `some()` will return true or false.

```
const similarity = (arr, values) => arr.filter(item => values.some(m => (m.id === item.id) && (m.name === item.name)));
```

my input:

```
let arr1 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "kiet"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'phan'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'tuan'
    }]

let arr2 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "kiet"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'haha'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'tuan'
    }
]
```

my result :

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'kiet' } ]
```

Comment: Can you please how example input?

Comment: do you have some data to illustrate the functionality and the result?

Comment: _"filter() can run when some() will return true or false"_ it is exactly how it works

Comment: Example:  `arr` is your collection of cards (each having id and name), `values` is my collection of cards (also having id an name each one). Your `similarity` function will return every of your `arr` cards that I also have.

Answer (score 0):

You are Filtering the array, then passing this condition inside the `some`

```
(m.id === item.id) && (m.name === item.name)
```

If the id of the second array (here, `m` is the second array's objects) is equal to the first array's id (here, `item` is the array's objects) and the name is equal to the first array's name property. If yes then it will return true. So the `filter` gets a true and if is does, it will return that particular object for which it gets a true

```js
let arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: "kiet" }, { id: 2, name: 'phan' }, { id: 3, name: 'tuan'}]
let arr2 = [ { id: 1, name: "kiet" }, { id: 2, name: 'haha' }, { id: 5, name: 'tuan' } ]
const similarity = (arr, values) => arr.filter(item => values.some(m => (m.id === item.id) && (m.name === item.name)));
console.log(similarity(arr1,arr2))
```

Comment: tks @weegee , now i knew how it work, tks you so much.

Comment: @TuấnKiệt wlcum hapy to hlp

Answer (score 0):

You get the elements from the array which have the same properties `id`/`name` as the values array.

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) needs a (kind of) boolean value and if `true` or [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then the item is taken to the new array.

[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) checks an item and if the callback returns a *truthy* value, then it returns `true`, if not then `false`.

```js
const
    similarity = (array, values) => array.filter(item => values.some(m => m.id === item.id && m.name === item.name)),
    arr1 = [ { id: 1, name: "kiet" }, { id: 2, name: 'phan' }, { id: 3, name: 'tuan' }],
    arr2 = [ { id: 1, name: "kiet" }, { id: 2, name: 'haha' }, { id: 5, name: 'tuan' }],
    result = similarity(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result);
```

For larger data sets, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), this is iterated once with a combined value and checked against for filtering.

```js
const
    similarity = (array, values) => {
        const
            getKey = ({ id, name }) => [id, name].join('|'),
            keys = new Set(values.map(getKey));

        return array.filter(o => keys.has(getKey(o)));
    },
    arr1 = [ { id: 1, name: "kiet" }, { id: 2, name: 'phan' }, { id: 3, name: 'tuan' }],
    arr2 = [ { id: 1, name: "kiet" }, { id: 2, name: 'haha' }, { id: 5, name: 'tuan' }],
    result = similarity(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -4):

This is a good technique if you want to check for array intersection.

```js
const vowels = [...'AEIOU'];
const isVowel = x => vowels.some(v => v === x);
const hasVowel = string => [...string].filter(isVowel).length > 0;
```